# Python gdb-module equivalent of x/i $pc

Tags: python, debugging, gdb

As the title suggests, I am trying to use Python's gdb module to extract the output of what typing 'x/i $pc' would give in gdb.
For instance, if typing x/i $pc would give
0x00000000 <main+0>: sub   $0x0,%rsp
Then I want to get the string 'sub    $0x0,%rsp'

I have tried searching through the python gdb documentation to figure this out, but the closest thing that I can find is `gdb.inferiors()[0].read_memory('address')`, which doesn't help me because that would return the memory in the wrong format.

Is there a way to do this other than parsing what would be returned by just calling `gdb.eval('x/i $pc', to_string=True)?`

Comment: I'm not sure the exact answer to this, but you should check out pdb, a python version of gdb. You can use python commands to evaluate the values of variables etc.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to use Python's gdb module to extract the output of what typing 'x/i $pc' would give in gdb.

```
(gdb) x/i $pc
=> 0x555555555129 <main+4>:     mov    $0x0,%eax

(gdb) py print(gdb.Architecture.disassemble(gdb.selected_frame().architecture(), gdb.selected_frame().pc()))
[{'length': 5, 'addr': 93824992235817L, 'asm': 'mov    $0x0,%eax'}]
```